# UNION ALL - return from which table the result is

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code running (Thanks to @Gordon Linoff).

```
SELECT alid, max(ts) as ts
FROM ((SELECT AL.alID, AL.al_date AS ts FROM AL)
      UNION ALL
      (SELECT MRA.mraNR, MRA.add_date FROM MRA)
      UNION ALL
      (SELECT AMG.mraNR, AMG.lastupd FROM AMG)
     ) t
GROUP BY alID
ORDER BY ts DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

Now we need to have a third value, knowing from which table the result comes (AL, MRA or AMG).
Already tried options like this, but nothing seems to work.

```
SELECT alid, TABLEVALUEWENEED as RES, max(ts) as ts
FROM ((SELECT AL.alID, TABLEVALUEWENEED AS RES1, AL.al_date AS ts FROM AL)
      UNION ALL
      (SELECT MRA.mraNR, TABLEVALUEWENEED AS RES2, MRA.add_date FROM MRA)
      UNION ALL
      (SELECT AMG.mraNR, TABLEVALUEWENEED AS RES3, AMG.lastupd FROM AMG)
     ) t
GROUP BY alID
ORDER BY ts DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

And, to get those tables values as php output like:

```
$RES1=$rows["RES1"];
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the string with the table name instead of `TABLEVALUEWENEED`:

```
SELECT alid, RES1, max(ts) as ts
FROM ((SELECT AL.alID, 'AL' AS RES1, AL.al_date AS ts FROM AL)
      UNION ALL
      (SELECT MRA.mraNR, 'MRA' AS RES1, MRA.add_date FROM MRA)
      UNION ALL
      (SELECT AMG.mraNR, 'AMG' AS RES1, AMG.lastupd FROM AMG)
     ) t
GROUP BY alID
ORDER BY ts DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

I also assume you wanted the alias to always be 'RES1' not 'RES1', 'RES2', 'RES3', because the name of the column will be the alias from the first `SELECT` of the `UNION` anyway.

Comment: what is `TABLEVALUEWENEED `?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, it's a placeholder in OPs second query.

Comment: I think you want return `RES1`. as OP want  `$RES1=$rows["RES1"];`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, ah, yes, missed that one. thanks for the edit.

Comment: Thank you guys so much! Now I also know how to add more values to it as well. It is running already! Thanks again!